# Showing a progress bar when downloading a file from the server

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, progress-bar

I need to show a progress bar to the user who requests a file to download. I am using J2EE application to generate the file. User will submit the form data to get the file. The server takes all the submitted data manipulates, generates and sends a PDF file back to Client.

So I want to show a progress bar to the user till the file comes to the Client side. 
Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: I would LOVE to know how to do this

Comment: How long does it usually take to generate the file?

Comment: @cherouvim: The time is not a static one here. It varies between file to file. It takes a minimum time of 1 sec to a maximum of 20-30 minutes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand you well, you want to show a progress bar until your server is ready to send a file, not to show the progress of the file beeing downloaded.

If that is true, you're dealing with a tough excercise. A reliable progressbar needs to know (pretty exact) what you're doing and how long it will take. In your case, there are lots of unreliable factors (one of them, maybe the biggest, is the web itself).

So most developers use some kind of an "endless" animation to display "work in progress".

**update**

Based on your comment, the easiest way to display a "work in progress" animation would look like

```
$.ajax({
    url:      "/myscripts/myserverscript",
    type:     "POST",
    data:     {
       foo: "bar"
    },
    dataType: "text",
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        // display a progress animation
    },
    complete: function(xhr, status){
        // hide the animation
    }
    ...
});
```

In the case of a single request. You may also setup a global ajax event handler for both (`.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxStop()`) to setup the show/hide functionallity.

References: [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [.ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/), [.ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)

Comment: Either of the cases is valid. It will be good to know the progress of the file being downloaded. Or I am still fine with showing an work in progress bar until the server is ready to send the file.

Comment: How to set the file download in ajax success method. I am able to get the file into the client side but don't know how to force the browser to download.

Answer (score 4):

**progress bar for server side file generation:**

We assume that the server needs many seconds to generate the file. This event is triggered by the original request, a blocking operation. When this finishes the file will have been generated and it'll be dispatched back to the client.

At the same time you want, via other requests (ajax), to be calling the server and getting a percentage back for the file which is currently being generated for the particular user.

The glue parts here are:

- when the original request is generating the file it needs to store the progress in frequent intervals (i.e every 10%). Storing this data in the http session will work OK.
- the other requests (ajax) simply need to be able to pull this information out of the http session
- synchronizing (serializing access) on the http session, something that some web apps commonly do, is out of the question, since the other requests (ajax) would simply block until the original request finished
- on the client side it's all html+javascript to provide the interaction you need (animated progress bar). Even if the intervals are very rough (jumping from 10% to 20% to 30%) you can animate the bar with jQuery. I've done it once in the past and it looks great.

**progress bar for file download:**

it's best to leave this to the browser's native dialog.

Comment: May I know how you get the file download information from the html/java-script ? Can you share some more information on the last point what u said (on the client side it's all ....)?

Comment: On the server side you'll need a URL (e.g a Java servlet) providing this information (simply printing the percentage from the http session). Whether this will be plain text (e.g "20%") or JSON or XML depends on you and how you'll implement the client side.  On the client side you'll do asynchronous requests on the URL via jQuery in order to get this information and modify the DOM accordingly. The requests will need to be triggered every X seconds (let's say 3 seconds) via the javascript function setTimeout(..)

Comment: For that kind of approach, I'd really suggest some kind of COMET way, not native ajax requests.

Comment: Thanks for your valid inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you just wrap a javax.swing.ProgressMonitorInputStream around the input stream, but be aware that unless the server is sending in chunked streaming mode the display won't really mean anything, as the entire response will have been read into memory before the first byte is delivered to Java.

Answer (score 0):

Using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) you can download file and show progress.

```
showProgressBar(); 
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Big_%26_Small_Pumkins.JPG', true);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onprogress = function (e) {
    console.log(e.loaded / e.total * 100);//shows downloaded percentage
    setProgressBarPercentage(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
}
xhr.onload = function () {
    hideProgressBar();
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.response);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', url);
    link.setAttribute('download', 'FILENAME');
    link.click();
}
xhr.send();
```